# Facebook Login Exception

Tags: facebook, laravel, api

I have this function that handle the Fb Callback.

```
    public function handleFbCallback() {
    if( !\Input::get('error', NULL) ) {
        try {
            $fuser = \Socialize::with('facebook')->user();
            $token = $fuser->token;
            if($fb = \App\UserFacebook::whereEmail($fuser->getEmail())->first()) {
                $fb->fb_id = $fuser->getId();
                $fb->nickname = $fuser->getNickname();
                $fb->name = $fuser->getName();
                $fb->avatar = $fuser->getAvatar();
                $fb->token = $token;
                $fb->save();

                $profile = \App\Profile::whereUserId($fb->user_id)->first();
                if($profile) {
                    $profile->name = $fuser->user['first_name'];
                    $profile->last_name = $fuser->user['last_name'];
                    $profile->save();
                } else {
                    \App\Profile::create([
                        'name' => $fuser->user['first_name'],
                        'last_name' => $fuser->user['last_name'],
                        'user_id' => $fb->user_id,
                     ]);
                }

                //load user and increments number login
                $user = \App\User::find($fb->user_id);
                if($user) {
                    $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $user->number_logins = $user->number_logins + 1;
                    $user->save();
                }

            }
            else {
                $password = str_random(8);
                $nuser = \App\User::whereEmail($fuser->getEmail())->first();
                if(!$nuser) {
                    $nuser = \App\User::create([
                        'email' => $fuser->getEmail(),
                        'password' => bcrypt($password),
                        'active' => 1,
                    ]);

                    if(\Session::get('source', NULL)) {
                        $nuser->source = \Session::get('source');
                        \Session::forget('source');
                    }

                    if(\Session::get('campaign', NULL)) {
                        $nuser->source = \Session::get('campaign');
                        \Session::forget('campaign');
                    }

                    $nuser->save();

                    //profile
                    \App\Profile::create([
                        'name' => $fuser->user['first_name'],
                        'last_name' => $fuser->user['last_name'],
                        'user_id' => $nuser->id,
                     ]);
                }
                $nuser->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $nuser->number_logins = 1;
                $nuser->save();

                $fb = \App\UserFacebook::create([
                    'fb_id' => $fuser->getId(),
                    'nickname' => $fuser->getNickname(),
                    'name' => $fuser->getName(),
                    'email' => $fuser->getEmail(),
                    'avatar' => $fuser->getAvatar(),
                    'token' => $token,
                    'user_id' => $nuser->id
                ]);
            }

            \Auth::loginUsingId($fb->user_id);
            if(\Session::get('custom_url', NULL) == 'thanks') {
                return redirect()->route('landing.thanks', array('social', $fb->user_id));
            } elseif($url = \Session::get('custom_url', NULL)) {
                \Session::forget('custom_url');
                return redirect($url);
            }
            return redirect()->intended();
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return redirect('/');

}
```

Running this function it make an exception:

Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?access_token=&appsecret_proof=cb32db5fac27b922d1a9c3040772a05b9a6e79f8145ee5a9fc21bbefd1f00909&fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,gender,verified` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)

But it make an exception about the token.
Someone have any idea to solve that?
Thank you!

Comment: I have the same code to a google + login and it works good.

Comment: nobody know?...

Comment: `access_token=&appsecret_proof=` - your access token seems to be empty.

Comment: How can I solve it?